# Clone and maximize a div

Tags: javascript, html, clone, maximize

I have a html-page with div's in one row, when I maximize one the other div's move, but I want all the div's to stay on their place and put the clone of the clicked on div (maximized one) in front of the others.

```js
function changeSize(id, weight, height){
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if(elem.getAttribute('style')){
        elem.removeAttribute('style');
    } else {
        elem.style.width = weight + 'px';
        elem.style.height = height + 'px';
        elem.style.fontSize = '30px';
    }
}

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('kaesten');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].onclick = function(){
        changeSize(this.id, 600, 600);
    }
}
```

```css
.kaesten{
 width:240px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:darkgrey;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000;
 border: 5px solid #F0F8ff;
 vertical-align:top;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #777;
 float:left;
 margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="kaesten">test1</div>
<div id="box2" class="kaesten">test2</div>
<div id="box3" class="kaesten">test3</div>
<div id="box4" class="kaesten">test4</div>
```

Question: How can I clone the clicked on div and do the changeSize style options?

Comment: `How can I clone the clicked on div and do the changeSize style options?` Do you want to do the `changeSize` on the cloned `div`? Where are you want to present the cloned `div`?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: exactly! I want to present the cloned div in the middle of the page!

Comment: can I add $( "." + id ).clone().appendTo( "new" + id ); in my JavaScript function?